# Visual Studio for android emulator is not working

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, appium, appium-android

I am trying to automate a native android app and I am using VS emulator for android device 6.0 android version. It freezes sometimes and I have to close and relaunch the emulator again and it works for a while and get the same freezing screen problem

[image]

How do I fix Visual Studio emulator for the android freezing problem?

Comment: Welcome to the community.  It us unclear what you are trying to do.  Please try to be more verbose.

Comment: @Sudeep Please add your comment above to your question. You are able to edit it yourself.

Comment: By adding intel hardware accelerated execution manager has helped a little bit.